# error downloading packages using yum

Tags: centos, permissions, yum

I was trying to update my packages i fired command `yum update` as root user but i then encountered error downloading packages and error number is **[Error 5] [Error 13] ** i don't know but its showing permission denied  , something like error downloading packages beacuse i don't have the permission to do so.
help please , i am not able to install any software on my centos too.

```
$ yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
You need to be root to perform this command.
(base) [ales@k8s-master ~]$ sudo yum update
[sudo] password for ales: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                       | 7.1 kB  00:00:00     
 * base: mirrors.praction.in
 * epel: sg.fedora.ipserverone.com
 * extras: mirrors.praction.in
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: mirror.vutbr.cz
 * updates: mirrors.praction.in
azure-cli                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
base                                                       | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
docker-ce-stable                                           | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                       | 5.3 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                     | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                              | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
jenkins                                                    | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
kubernetes/signature                                       |  454 B  00:00:00     
kubernetes/signature                                       | 1.4 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
https://miktex.org/download/fedora/30/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://miktex.org/download/fedora/30/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
https://miktex.org/download/fedora/30/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://miktex.org/download/fedora/30/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
Trying other mirror.
miktex-fedora-28                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
rpmfusion-free-updates                                     | 3.7 kB  00:00:00     
teamviewer                                                 | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                    | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
virtualbox/7/x86_64/signature                              |  181 B  00:00:00     
virtualbox/7/x86_64/signature                              | 2.9 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.6-3.3.el7 will be updated
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.10-3.2.el7 will be an update
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.2-3.el7 will be updated
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 3:19.03.3-3.el7 will be an update
---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.2-3.el7 will be updated
---> Package docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.3-3.el7 will be an update
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-11 will be updated
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-12 will be an update
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:77.0.3865.90-1 will be updated
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:77.0.3865.120-1 will be an update
---> Package x264-libs.x86_64 0:0.148-23.20170521gitaaa9aa8.el7 will be updated
---> Package x264-libs.x86_64 0:0.148-24.20170521gitaaa9aa8.el7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==================================================================================
 Package              Arch   Version                 Repository              Size
==================================================================================
Updating:
 containerd.io        x86_64 1.2.10-3.2.el7          docker-ce-stable        23 M
 docker-ce            x86_64 3:19.03.3-3.el7         docker-ce-stable        24 M
 docker-ce-cli        x86_64 1:19.03.3-3.el7         docker-ce-stable        39 M
 epel-release         noarch 7-12                    epel                    15 k
 google-chrome-stable x86_64 77.0.3865.120-1         google-chrome           59 M
 x264-libs            x86_64 0.148-24.20170521gitaaa9aa8.el7
                                                     rpmfusion-free-updates 556 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================
Upgrade  6 Packages

Total download size: 147 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for google-chrome
No Presto metadata available for docker-ce-stable
No Presto metadata available for rpmfusion-free-updates
Failed to download prestodelta for repository epel: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied


Error downloading packages:
  3:docker-ce-19.03.3-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  containerd.io-1.2.10-3.2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  epel-release-7-12.noarch: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  1:docker-ce-cli-19.03.3-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  google-chrome-stable-77.0.3865.120-1.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
  x264-libs-0.148-24.20170521gitaaa9aa8.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Does the error persist if you come out of the Conda environment and run the command?

Comment: Oops i haven't noticed that , let me try it and then i will tell you!

Comment: still persists @NasirRiley